# SSRS Scope error

Tags: reporting-services

I have the following Query to create a table :

```
 SELECT
   l.aliasnaam
  ,l.kultivar
  ,l.SkattingVirKult
  ,l.GelewerVirKult
  ,l.PersentKlaarKult
FROM
   LeweringVsSkatting as l
GROUP BY
   l.aliasnaam
  ,l.kultivar
  ,l.SkattingVirKult
  ,l.GelewerVirKult
  ,l.PersentKlaarKult
```

I want to add a gradient color in the column `PersentKlaarKult` with the following expression in the textbox background :

```
=Code.ColorDWB(sum(Fields!PersentKlaarKult.Value)
              ,Max(Fields!PersentKlaarKult.Value, “DataSet1”)
              ,Min(Fields!PersentKlaarKult.ValueFields!, “DataSet1”)
              ,“#2322EE”
              )
```

However I get the following error:

> The BackgroundColor expression for the text box ‘PersentKlaarKult’ has a scope parameter that is not valid for an aggregate function.  The scope parameter must be set to a string constant that is equal to either the name of a containing group, the name of a containing data region, or the name of a dataset.

Any help would be much appreciated.
Regards

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are missing your dataset name in your `sum` function:

```
=Code.ColorDWB(sum(Fields!PersentKlaarKult.Value, “DataSet1”)
              ,Max(Fields!PersentKlaarKult.Value, “DataSet1”)
              ,Min(Fields!PersentKlaarKult.Value, “DataSet1”)
              ,“#2322EE”
              )
```

Comment: Thank you iamdave. I have corrected my expression. However I get the same error message.

Comment: You seem to have a typo? ValueFields! at the end of line 3?
If that was just a typo on this post and not in your code then I would suggest creating 3 text boxes and setting the expression of each to the three parts of your current expression. i.e. sum(Fields!PersentKlaarKult.Value, “DataSet1”) for the first one. This way you can see which part is causing the error before you worry about calling the ColorDWB function.

Comment: @Canadean_AS  Thanks, I just copied the expression from the question and added in the dataset name, though this could also be the problem.

Comment: @iamdave, it was the OP I was asking, sorry I should have directed the comment at them

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your field Expression

```
=IIF(sum(Fields!PersentKlaarKult.Value, “DataSet1”) = “Blue”, “#2322EE”,
,IIF(Max(Fields!PersentKlaarKult.Value, “DataSet1”) = “Blue”, “#2322EE”,
,IIF(Min(Fields!PersentKlaarKult.Value, “DataSet1”) = “Blue”, “#2322EE”, “Blue”)))
```